# I can import bs4 to IDLE but not to other IDE's like Spyder or Pycharm

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Many threads have been written on this subject, and I still can't figure it out.  I installed bs4 via command line, and it imports just fine on IDLE, but I can't import it on Spyder.  I get the standard error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

I've uninstalled and reinstalled the most recent versions of Spyder and Python 3.9.  They're both on C: drive, and entering "pip list" to the command prompt confirms that beautifulsoup4 is installed.

I have a vague hypothesis that the solution has something to do with adding a path to Spyder's PYTHONPATH Manager, so I entered in the address for bs4, yet that did nothing either.

Comment: Are Spyder and Pycharm using virtual environments that don't inherit from the global installed packages?

Comment: I'm a beginner to coding, so to be totally honest, I don't even understand the meaning of your question and how I'd be able to look into it.

I will say that I randomly installed numpy, and that package imports just fine on both IDLE and spyder.

Comment: If you go into Pycharm and open the "Terminal" in the bottom left (not "Python Console"), does it show `(venv)` before the path? And if in *that* console you run `pip list`, does it show the packages you're looking for?

Comment: If `pip list` doesn't show the package, you installed BS4 into a different directory than where Pycharm is looking (basically). The simple fix (although it wastes some space) is just to run `pip install bs4` again *inside of the Pycharm terminal* to reinstall it where Pycharm is looking. The better fix is to read up on virtual environments, and either avoid using them (you may have accidentally set one up when creating the project), or set up a virtual environment for your project, and use that environment everywhere you want to use those specific packages.

Comment: Thanks for these comments.  Yes, Pycharm's terminal says (venv), and when I tried entering pip list, the terminal said there's no Python in that directory at all!